# How to capture virtual keyboard hiding on div click in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, virtual-keyboard

Currently working on a solution which uses same solution for both mobile and desktop web. However, a issue arises when user clicks on link which should take user to a new component, instead it only hides the virtual keyboard and keeps the user on the same view. This is not constant. Happens every now and then.

**Problem:** don't know how to even capture this issue on debugging. The problem only occurs when I try on a physical phone(only tried with chrome on Android). Not on `chrome` browser with mobile view.

**Tried** to point down to the component where it might be occurring. But no idea where to pin point the issue?

My code can be viewed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/shaza/vt14r2wo/)

Comment: Could you show code of the component where it occurs please?

Comment: Code link added to the post.